# What is the simplest way to parse a json string in linux console?

Tags: json, linux, bash, sh

I need a simple way to parse a json string received as a parameter.

Is there a console tool for doing that?

I'll like to have something like this:

```
data=parsestring('{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}')
echo data.field1
echo data.field2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jq` if possible:

```
$ echo '{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}' | jq
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2"
}

$ echo '{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}' | jq '.field1'
"value1"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. 
What I had to do is to install jq. 

> sudo apt-get install jq

Comment: If source json is in a string it can be passed to jq as a json argument rather than piped with echo: `json='{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}'; jq -n --argjson j "$json" '$j, $j.field1'`